# SQL - Getting multiple into one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting my feet wet with databases and MySQL. I am writing my own dump file to import a database and was curious if there was a way to import multiple items into one attribute.

For example, say I am building a database of songs with the attributes Artist, Album, Title, Year. If a particular song appears on multiple albums (such as an original release and then later on a Greatest Hits album, or a movie soundtrack...) is there any way to put multiple albums into one entry?

```
create table Music (
  Artist text,
  Album text,
  Title text,
  Year integer,
  primary key (Title),
);
```

For instance something like:

```
insert into Music values
  ("The Beatles", "Yellow Submarine" && "Greatest Hits", "All You Need Is Love", 1967);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have never heard about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Because "The Beatles", "All You Need Is Love" are repeated, you have to have a separate table with this titles (one table for bands, another for songs) and link this table to your Music table by the primary key

Comment: What @zaratustra said is spot on. With your idea of multiple values in the same field, you're going against the intention of a relational database. That is: If you have a many-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, the related data needs to go in a separate table (or two, in case of many-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can insert multiple records at the same time like this

```
insert into Music (Artist, Album, Title, Year)
values ('The Beatles', 'Yellow Submarine', 'All You Need Is Love', 1967),
       ('The Beatles', 'Greatest Hits', 'All You Need Is Love', 1967);
```

Comment: Generally a good example, but in this case there is a primary key constraint on title.

Comment: I was trying to put both of the album titles into one record, not insert two record at one time. However, your answer in combination with the comments by zaratrustra and UweB have opened my eyes a little bit as to what the relational model is all about.